# jboss eap 7 - WFLYCTL0030

Tags: jboss7.x, jolokia

we use jolokia-1.6.2.war in JBoss to monitor the application.
something.ear and activemq-rar.rar are our deployables.
we have jolokia war inside our something.ear. So our something.ear looks like below

```
jolokia-1.6.2.war, 
xxx-ejb.jar, 
yyy-rest.war, 
aaa-web.war
```

With JBoss EAP 6.4 everything works without errors.
But with JBoss EAP 7.4 we get the following error every time we start JBoss:

```
12:34:07,820 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-resource-description") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
("resource-adapter" => "activemq-rar.rar"),
("connection-definitions" => "OpusSyncAlertBlockerAck"),
("statistics" => "extended")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
("resource-adapter" => "activemq-rar.rarr"),
("connection-definitions" => "OpusSyncAlertBlockerAck"),
("statistics" => "extended")
]"
```

I guess Jolokia polls the MBeans from activemq-rar.rar before it's deployed and that's where the error comes from?

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Got a corresponding log entry with another resource adapter. Undeploying jolokia.war (1.7.1) made the message disappear.

Comment: under wildfly-26.1.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a mistake in your configuration according to the JBoss configuration object model. To be specific, the error means the node in the object model doesn't exist! I would suggest using the CLI and by using the tab key (auto-completion) you can determine which portion of the configuration has an error.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. The issue is jolokia start to make statistics call before the resources are ready. But the jboss server is started successfully, no issues. With jboss6 we didn't face this issue but we face this issue in jboss7